# Selenium Webdriver freeze Firefox after download exactly 10 files

Tags: python, windows, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I have problem with Selenium Webdriver and Python (on Windows). When my script try to download 25 files one by one (from this same website) - after 10 successfully downloads Firefox is not responding and Selenium is blocked. I'm running Firefox with preferences:

```
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain,text/csv")
```

Is there a limit for downloads with Selenium...?
I tried this in 3 different webpages and it's weird, because always it freeze after download 10 files.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Webdriver+Python+RobotFramework and Firefox. I have 30 tests in a suite and Firefox always freezes on 14th. My colleague encountered similar problem with same tech stack and a For loop, when Firefox freezes on 11th iteration. Could it be a bug  in firefox+python webdriver?

Comment: Do you have Firefox 25.0.1? Try with Firefox 24, this solved my problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460549/selenium-webdriver-and-firefox-crashes-after-download-a-few-csv-files).

Answer (score 1):

I found that reinitializing the webdriver instance for each page interaction worked for me. So, open and close the instance for each file. I read that Selenium works best off clean slates.

Having monitored the system resources while running my script I noticed huge CPU usage for a menial task. My understanding is that by reinitializing it, It is less complicated for Selenium to interpret.