# Selenium Webdriver and Firefox crashes after download a few CSV files

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I have problem with download about 20 files (one by one, from one website) using Selenium Webdriver + Firefox (25.0.1), in Python 2.7.6 (Windows), but after download 9-10 files Firefox is blocked and is not responding... this happend every time, really strange for me. 
How can I fix it?

Here is my test code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

fx = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fx.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fx.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain,text/csv,application/csv,application/octet-stream,text/comma-separated-values")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fx)

for i in range(20):
    browser.get("http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v41r1/topic/com.ibm.ismsaas.doc/reference/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv")
    print i
    time.sleep(1)
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried this with 5 different websites and different file types and size - always identical problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know what the problem is - just Firefox 25.0.1. On Firefox 24 everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

We are using iMacros and not Selenium, but I assume our solution can be reused here: Restart Firefox after every download to avoid Firefox memory leaks.

Comment: Yeah, this is solution, but I can't do that, because after every restart of Firefox I must log in to website, from which I want to download files, and in log in process I use Sikuli - this would take a lot of time for download 20 files...

Comment: you can use firefox profile , start a driver with firefox profile, which you already logged in